# how to reset prefix: npm config set prefix /usr/local

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I was trouble shooting the "`ionic: command not found`" issue.

I found posts suggesting to try: `npm config set prefix /usr/local`.

But I typed "`npm config set prefix /usr/loca`" on accident.

Now if I try to run any npm command it will just throw errors:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/usr/loca'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:201:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:171:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: did you figure this out I am facing thge same issue

Comment: I think it was a version issue. I think I tried a older npm version eventually worked.

Comment: Is it enough to edit your ~/.npmrc to reset the prefix there?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the whitespace in your username string after space with "~1".

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Took me about 2 hours to figure this out. Thought it might help people who are facing a similar issue.

The problem is with:

```
% npm config set prefix /usr/loca
```

As you can notice from the above, I forgot the letter 'l' at the end of the line leading to npm config setting my 'prefix' to `/usr/loca` [this is my understanding of the issue. Feel free to correct me as I am new to Node world]

Now, when I try and run -

```
% npx create-react-app myApp
```

I got an error as -

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/usr/loca'

Because there is no directory by name 'loca'.
Few suggestions about disabling SIP to make it work are there but I think it's not a good idea. Anyway, here are the steps I took to resolve the issue -

Step 1 : On your terminal get into root account by typing --> sudo -I

Step 2: Enter your root credential password

Step 3: Clear npm cache by force --> npm cache clean --force

Step 4: Install latest npm --> npm install -g npm@latest --force

Step 5: Clear npm cache again --> npm cache clean --force

Step 6: You should be good now. Check your npm version --> rpm -v

Step 7: 'exit' out of root

Step 8: Set prefix properly this time --> npm config set prefix /usr/local

Step 9: npx create-react-app client

Step 10: Type 'Y' to install create-react-app package

If everything went well, you should see a 'Happy Hacking' message as the last line.